# Недо- или не до-?

Tags: орфография

Не( )довязанный бабушкой свитер - слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Возможны варианты. Фраза, приведённая целиком, дала бы подсказку.

Answer (score 3):

> Не( )довязанный бабушкой свитер - слитно или раздельно?

**Раздельно.**

Из учебника Кайдаловой и Калининой «Современная русская орфография» (1983):

> Частица *не* с полными причастиями пишется раздельно, если есть пояснительные слова (не наречия степени): *На столе напёрсток, **не довязанный старушкою** чулок* (Ч.) ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не противоречат такой трактовке правил и пособия Розенталя, Валгиной...

См., к примеру: Сборник диктантов для вечерней (сменной) средней общеобразовательной школы / Н. С. Валгина, Д. Э. Розенталь, М. И. Фомина, В. В. Цапукевич. - Москва : Учпедгиз, 1962:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос задан задан 15 марта, а сегодня уже 21 марта. А вот на несколько последних вопросов никто не отвечает...

Comment: Ну хороших ответов можно ждать вечность. А вот быстрых, но бестолковых ответов и без нас очень много...

Comment: Без нас? А вы кого имеете в виду? Поясните пожалуйста, очень интересно.

Comment: Где же ответ?  Отмалчиваться – это не очень корректная привычка. Вы кого-нибудь конкретно имели в виду или весь коллектив в целом? Если уж начали говорить, то закончите свою мысль.

Comment: Мысль вполне закончена. Я уже отвечал вам, что не нанимался пояснять простые вещи.

Answer (score 2):

1. Здесь следует использовать **слитное написание**, приставка НЕДО со значением незаконченного действия: **недовязанный бабушкой свитер**.

**Недо/вязать** – недо/вязанный – недовязанный бабушкой.

Из словарей:

Управление в русском языке: **НЕДОВЯЗАТЬ** что / чего. Недовязать кофту; Недовязать сетей на весь сезон рыбной ловли. См. недо- (приставка).

Орфографический словарь: ***недовязать***, -яжу, -яжет (вязкой не довести до готовности)

Причастие «недовязанный»  используется в литературе:   На его груди спал жирнущий поповский кот, уткнув морду в ***недовязанный*** чулок. [В. Я. Шишков.]

2. Раздельное написание НЕ можно было бы предположить при наличии в предложении падежной формы «до конца», например:  ***Не довязанный до конца** свитер лежал рядом.*

**Довязать** – довязанный – не довязанный до конца.

Однако в словаре для слова ***недовязанный*** форма "до конца" уже присутствует (тогда в предложении она будет лишней), поэтому раздельное письмо в приведенном примере из вопроса **нежелательно**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 22.03.2021**

Отвечая на вопрос, я использовала материалы из Нацкорпуса, при этом пыталась найти сочетание «не довязанный» с раздельным написанием НЕ. Но там не было **ни одного примера**, и это тоже повлияло на мое решение.

Но вот **нашелся пример**, да еще у Чехова!  Разумеется,  мне стало интересно: что же там за контекст, которого нам так не хватало?

http://poesias.ru/proza/chehov-anton-pavlovich/chehov10421.shtml

«*Много я видал на своем веку домов, больших и малых, каменных и деревянных, старых и новых, но особенно врезался мне в память один дом…»*

Далее следует очень подробное описание дома:

*«На стене портрет какого-то архиерея, написанный масляными красками. От архиерея идет ряд предков с желто-лимонными, цыганскими физиономиями. **На столе наперсток, катушка ниток и недовязанный чулок**, на полу выкройки и черная кофточка с живыми нитками».*

**А где же  старушка?!**

У кого спрашивать, у Кайдаловой и Калининой? Вот так наши составители правил обращались с классическими текстами. Но и цитировать эти правила нужно **ответственно,** если вы с уважением относитесь **не только к ним**, но и к русскому языку тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

Прежде чем  применять современное правило из учебника Кайдаловой и Калининой 1983 года, надо разобраться **с приставкой НЕДО**. Если причастие образовано от глагола  с этой приставкой, то никакое правило  не поможет **разделить эту приставку на две части** в причастии, которое является глагольной формой.

1. **Приставка НЕДО**

НЕ с глаголом пишется слитно, если в его состав входит приставка НЕДО со значением недостаточности действия: ему **недостаёт** выдержки, **недосмотреть** за ребёнком, он что-то **недосказывает**.

Замечаю, брат, что ты приуныл; говори прямо: чего тебе **недостает**?

Еще кого **недосчитались** вы?

Он жил скупо; **недоедал, недопивал**, одевался бог знает как.

И как **недосмотрел!** И как **недослышал!**

Видимо, у нас сейчас просто **недостаёт** воображения.

2. **Сочетание НЕ + ДО**

Приставку НЕДО со значением недостаточности действия следует отличать от сочетания  **частицы НЕ и приставки  ДО**  со значением **«доведения действия до конца».**   В этом случае глагол часто управляет существительным с **предлогом ДО**, которое   можно вставить  для проверки: **не досмотреть** фильм  (до конца), шест **не достаёт** до дна, не досказать, не дослушать.

Она **не дослушала,** отошла прочь.

Но никогда **не досмотрел** Гришаня ни одного фильма, **не дочитал** ни одной книги.

Он **не досказал**, махнул рукой, и всё остальное время мы ехали молча.

**Не досмотрел, не доработал, не дожил**,  отправился туда, где нет ни снов, ни болезней, а жизнь бесконечна.

3. Надо сказать, что многие авторы пишут НЕ+ДО во всех случаях,  даже когда очевидно, что речь идет о приставке НЕДО, например:

Обошли его, и он чего-то **не досмотрел.**

Побывал в мастерской: ― кабы **не досмотрел**, проквасили шерсть.

**Не достает** только, чтобы в газетах напечатали.

А что **не достает** ста пятидесяти рублей, это только частность.

При такой погоде **не достает** смелости идти под парусами.

Но в  некоторых случаях выбрать вариант **не так просто**, приходится подумать.

4. Вот и в приведенном примере нет особой сложности в том, чтобы применить всем известное правило. Но прежде надо **доказать, что это не приставка НЕДО**. Я такого доказательства в ответе не вижу.

Comment: Очень понравилось!

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваше мнение.